# L'Hopital rule variation

Tags: calculus

> If 
>   $$
> \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)= \infty\quad \lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=\infty$$  and 
>   $$
> \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L
> $$ 
>   then
>   $$
> \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L 
> $$

Is this correct? Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: This is just L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @Jason Indeed it is.

Comment: But I mean, the title of the question is "L'Hospital's role [sic]  *variation*", but this is not a variation, this is just literally L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Original L'Hopital's rule: <br/>

Comment: @Jason you're right

Comment: Original L'Hopital's rule: <br/> If $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=0 \quad$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=0 \quad$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L \quad}$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L \quad$ and it has a reasoning.

Comment: Any formulation of L'Hopital's rule I've ever seen says that $lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ and both are equal to either $0$ or $\pm\infty$.

Comment: If $\quad \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=0 \quad $ and $\quad \lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=0 \quad$  and $\quad \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L, \quad $ then  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L $$

Comment: @shapoor This is as well one of the cases in which L'Hopital's can be applied.

Comment: and the reasoning?

Comment: @shapoor you mean the proof for L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: the proof for the question. because I know the proof of the original statement, which I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @but, what you asked is exactly L'Hopital's rule :s

Comment: so prove L'Hopital rule please.

Comment: @shapoor The are already answers you can look at [Case infinity over infinity](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/147356/297952). [Case 0/0](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/250356/297952)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ give you an indeterminate form "$\frac {\infty}{\infty}$" and from here L'Hopital rule can be applied, and since you know: $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=L$ is correct assuming L is a finite value.

Comment: Reasoning please.

Comment: I'm just using the fact fact that $lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = \infty$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = \infty$ therefore $lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ is an indeterminate form "$\frac {\infty}{\infty}$" which is one of the cases in which you can apply [L'Hopital's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is correct according to the theorem.

If  lim x-> a  F (x)/g(x) = L

Hence lim x-> a  f '(x)/g '(x) =L

And vice versa

Comment: The first does not imply the second.

Answer (score 0):

Which is exactly right and what I explicitly stated earlier

0/0  and inf/inf are indeterminate forms  hence Lhopital stands as quoted