# Prove $\lim \limits_{x \to\infty } \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$ and $f$ differentiable implies $ \lim \limits_{x \to\infty } \inf |f'(x)|=0 $

Tags: limits, derivatives

Given a differentiable function on $(a,+\infty)$ such as $\lim \limits_{x \to\infty } \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$ prove the following:
$$ \lim \limits_{x \to\infty } \inf |f'(x)|=0  $$

I just can't see how to do it...
(even after understanding [How to show that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$ implies $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62916/how-to-show-that-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fx-0-implies-lim-limits-x))

Comment: For some $\epsilon > 0,$ what happens if $f'(x) > \epsilon$ for all $x > X_0,$ where $X_0$ is some large positive number? The other case is, what happens if $f'(x) < - \epsilon$ with everything else written the same?

Comment: @WillJagy than f(x) is monotonically increasing to infinity, but it doesn't yet a contradict

Comment: Anyway, there is still a little more to it after that, but it is a start.

Comment: User, yes, monotone to infinity, and what about $f(x) / x?$

Comment: Or, what about $(f(x)-f(X_0)) / (x - X_0)?$

Comment: @WillJagy Well, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ could be any number, the last expression is positive (mean value theorem) but I just can't see how to continue (but thank you for the comments any way)

Comment: @User - with Will's bound, roughly speaking $f$ grows at least linearly, since for $f'(x) = \epsilon$ it would be growing like a line...now $f(x)/x$ is measuring how fast $f$ grows compared to a linear function...

Comment: @uncookedfalcon oh, I think I understand now, at least intuitively...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It suffices to show that there exists a sequence $x_n\to \infty$ such that $f'(x_n)\to 0$.

By the mean value theorem, for each $n$ there exists $x_n$ with $n<x_n<2n$ such that 
$$
f'(x_n) = \frac{f(2n)-f(n)}{2n-n}=\frac{f(2n)-f(n)}{n}=2\frac{f(2n)}{2n}-\frac{f(n)}{n}.
$$
Since $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)/x=0$, it follows that the right hand side tends to zero, and hence
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} f'(x_n)=0.
$$
By the squeeze theorem, the fact that $x_n>n$ implies that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=\infty.
$$
This finishes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

In case $f'(x)>\epsilon$ for all $x\geq x_0$ then (show that) $f(x)>f(x_0)+\epsilon(x-x_0)$ for all $x\geq x_0$.
 Then show that $f(x)>f(x_0)+\epsilon(x-x_0)>\frac{\epsilon}{2}x$ for all $x\geq x_1$ for some $x_1\geq x_0$...