# A question about limits and derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable such that $f'(x)\to l$ as $x\to \infty$. Prove that $ \frac{f(x)}{x}\to l $ as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Hospital?${}{}{}$

Comment: I am looking for a more analytical proof. Besides how do we apply Hospital's. We need to first show that f(x) tends to infinity as x does.

Comment: @LavKumar No, LHR does not require that $f\to \infty$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62916/how-to-show-that-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fx-0-implies-lim-limits-x) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'(x)\to \ell$, then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $x_0$ such that $\ell-\epsilon< f'(x)<\ell +\epsilon$ whenever $x>x_0$.

From the mean value theorem, we have

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(\xi)(x-x_0)$$

for some $\xi \in (x_0,x)$.  But then we can write for $x>x_0$

$$\frac{f(x_0)}{x}+\left(1-\frac{x_0}{x}\right)(\ell -\epsilon)<\frac{f(x)}{x}<\frac{f(x_0)}{x}+\left(1-\frac{x_0}{x}\right)(\ell +\epsilon)$$

Letting $x\to \infty$ we see that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have

$$\ell -\epsilon<\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}<\ell +\epsilon$$

and hence $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\ell$ as was to be shown!

Comment: Thank you. This really helped !

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.