# Simple L'Hopital Question

Tags: analysis, limits

> I know from definition, that the L'Hopital Rule is the following;
>   [image]

This includes the case $0/0$ and $\dfrac{+-\infty}{+- \infty}$ ... but my question is can LHopital be used on any type of limit like $\dfrac{anything}{\infty}$ ?? this is not mentioned commonly online or in my lecture notes , but is shown in case 2 of the wikipedia article proof;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Yes, it can.${}$

Comment: Probably not mentioned in your lecture because it's not easy to replicate (write problems that have $\frac{c}{\infty}$). If Wiki says so, then it's probably right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as I mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51629/242) there is a more general form of the rule,  e.g. below from from Rudin's $\:$ *Principles of Mathematical Analysis,* $\:$  1976. It requires only that the denominator $\to\infty.\,$ For further such generalizations see the Monthly papers [cited here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11236/another-limit-task-x-over-ln-x-lhopital-wont-do-it/11252#11252)

[image]